# How can i move all the html component to the center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in HTML I want to ask this question.
how can I move all the items in the center of the page?
see the picture below
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When you ask a question try adding the code you have written. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just, make div contains your from and make it's style align: center; as example below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>welcome</p>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<form>
  <label for="x1">Input x1:</label>
  <input type="text" id="x1" name="x1"><br>
  <label for="x2">Input x2:</label>
  <input type="text" id="x2" name="x2"><br>
  <button type="button">Compute</button><br>
  <button type="button">Clean</button><br>
  <label for="Midpoint">Midpoint result:</label>  
  <input type="text" id="Midpoint" name="Midpoint" placeholder="Try again"><br>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so mush, it works, could i change the radius of the textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You need use flexbox and wrap items inside block with fix size.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent__inner {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__inner">
     <!-- child items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but i think iam so bignner, so i haven't understand your code.

Comment: it will be better, if there is another way to do this function instead of css code.

Comment: There's a lot of css tutorials online if you need. In short though, you can put the above css in a `<style>` element in the `<head>` of the page or link to it in a `.css` file and put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` in the head

Answer (score 0):

You must use css styles or add attribute style="text-align: center" to form element.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, you can use the  tag (however, you cannot use it in HTML 5, because it does not support it). So if you use HTML 4, you can use it.
In your CSS code, you can use "text-align: center;"(do not include the double quotes)

Comment: *In your HTML code, you can use the tag*, which tag are you refering to? Please add some detail so your answer can be more clear.

Comment: I really don't think `text-align: center;` is deprecated in HTML 5

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one, just use the `<center>` tag : )